# Slack web API issue with a method user.list

Tags: ruby, slack, slack-api

I am using ruby to make calls to the Slack API, I have a problem when I want to use the users.list method, when I make the request I get this:

```
[+] Received slash command [/slack-list] | User: Jhon | Params: 
undefined method `users' for #<Slack::Web::Client:0x00007ff67419e048 @proxy=nil, @user_agent="Slack Ruby Client/1.1.0", @ca_path="/usr/lib/ssl/certs", @ca_file="/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem", @logger=#<Slack::Logger:0x00007ff67419d828 @level=2, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007ff67419d710 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007ff67419d5f8 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @binmode=false, @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00007ff67419d5a8>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=6320>>, @endpoint="https://slack.com/api/", @token="xoxb-3200679304454-3716991152342-AOpXSiKGwrH0aIqumHrrgqsP", @timeout=nil, @open_timeout=nil, @default_page_size=100, @default_max_retries=100, @adapter=:net_http>
Did you mean?  users_id
```

This is my code:

```
token = Figaro.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN


Slack.configure do |config|
config.token = token
end

client = Slack::Web::Client.new
puts client.users.list
```

Anyone know's why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
token = Figaro.env.SLACK_API_TOKEN


Slack.configure do |config|
config.token = token
end

client = Slack::Web::Client.new
puts client.users_list()
```

https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list